# How to reinstall /bin/sh

Tags: shell, debian, reinstall

I have accidentally deleted `/bin/sh`, and I am trying to to re-install it.
If I type `sh` in the terminal, It says

```
The program 'sh' can be found in the following packages:
 * bash
 * dash
```

If I try to `apt-get install bash`, I get

```
bash is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
```

So, how am I supposed to get `/bin/sh` back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sudo ln -s dash /bin/sh`.  The "dash" package should already have set this symlink in its post-installation routines.

Comment: I think you mean bash...?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is the Bourne shell equivalent, which in the case of the OP, is `dash`.

Comment: I meant "I think you mean `sudo ln -s bash /bin/sh`."

Comment: No, i meant what I said: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2011-05-03 11:01 /bin/sh -> dash` on Ubuntu; on Solaris and FreeBSD, `/bin/sh` was a smaller, statically linked version of the Bourne shell; I can't remember about HP-UX, AIX and IRIX, but it wasn't `bash`.  As I said, `/bin/sh` should be the closest to the Bourne shell.  If using bash syntax, then `#!/bin/bash` should always be specified.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
apt-get --reinstall install bash
```

Comment: I tried that and I got the following:
>E: Sub-process /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || >true returned an error code (100)
>E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure >--apt || true

Comment: @AdelCKod Try `ln -s bash /bin/sh`, and then enzotib's answer.  Also, learn from whatever mistake you made that resulted in the removal, and try to never make it again.

Comment: @jw013 No, it works, but is not the default. @Arcege is right: `/bin/sh` was not `bash` in his **Debian** system, it was `dash`, the _Debian Almquist Shell_.